# Can we choose the kernel of a Hilbert-Schmidt integral operator $T$ s.t. $0\in\sigma_p(T)$, $0\in\sigma_c(T)$ or $0\in\sigma_c(T)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $(\Omega_i,\mathcal A_i,\mu_i)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $k\in L^2(\mu_1\otimes\mu_2)$. We know that $$Tf:=\int k(\;\cdot\;,x_2)f(x_2)\;\;\;\text{for }f\in L^2(\mu_2)$$ is a linear Hilbert-Schmidt operator from $L^2(\mu_2)$ to $L^2(\mu_1)$. In particular, $T$ is compact and hence $\sigma(T)\setminus\{0\}=\sigma_p(T)\setminus\{0\}$.

> Can we choose $k$ such that
>
> 1. $0\in\sigma_p(T)$;
> 2. $0\in\sigma_c(T)$;
> 3. $0\in\sigma_r(T)$?

I'm also interested in the same question, but with a more general (but still compact) integral operator and would be very happy if someone could provide a good reference on that.

Answer (score 0):

To make life simple let us assume that both measure spaces coincide with ${\mathbb N}=\{1, 2, 3, \ldots \}$  under counting measure.  Thus the integral
kernel
$$
  k=(k_{i, j})_{i, j\in {\mathbb N}}
  $$
turns out to be the same thing as  the matrix of the associated integral operator on $\ell^2$,  relative to the standard orthonormal basis.

Choosing
$$
  k(i, j) = \left\{ \matrix{
  \displaystyle\frac1{i}, & \text{if } i=j, \cr
  0, & \text{otherwise},
  }\right.
  $$
gives rise to the  diagonal operator with matrix
$$
  \left[\matrix{
  1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots  \cr
  0 & \frac12 & 0 & \cdots  \cr
  0 & 0 & \frac13 & \cdots  \cr
  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \cr
  }\right]
  $$
which is injective and has  dense range, hence $0$ lies in the continuous spectrum of $T$.
If we instead take
$$
  \left[\matrix{
  0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots  \cr
  1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots  \cr
  0 & \frac12 & 0 & \cdots  \cr
  0 & 0 & \frac13 & \cdots  \cr
  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \cr
  }\right]
  $$
we get what is sometimes called a weighted shift, and which is again injective, but its range is not dense because it
is orthogonal to the first basis vector.  Consequently $0$ lies in the residual  spectrum of $T$.

Finally,  the zero operator has $0$ in its point spectrum.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With your first choice of $k$, $T$ is just the multiplication operator by $\left(\frac1i\right)_{i\in\mathbb N}\in\ell^\infty$, i.e. $$Tx=\left(\frac{x_i}i\right)_{i\in\mathbb N}\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in\ell^2,$$ right? It's clear to me that $T$ is injective and we should see that is has dense range as follows: If $x\in\ell^2$, then $$x^n_i:=(x_1,2x_2,\ldots,nx_n,0,\ldots)\in\ell^2$$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ and $$\left\|x-Tx^n\right\|_{\ell^2}=\sum_{i>n}|x_i|^2\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0,$$ right? But how do we prove that the range is not all of $\ell^2$?

Comment: $(1/i)_{i\in\mathbb N}$ is not in the range.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed. Thank you.